# how to loop same key to get different associated value in json/object

Tags: jquery, json, object

i have json/object like this

```
{city: "bangalore", other:"other data", pic: "bangalore.jpg",city: "delhi", pic: "delhi.jpg"}
```

i have 2 cities and its pic. i want to append them into seperate 2 div.

**here i'm trying to loop through each city only? but failed**    how can i do that?

```
$.ajax({
      url: "mul.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        a: a
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(obj.city); // i'm getting only delhi , what about bangalore?
        $.each(obj.city, function(i, city) {
          console.log(city); // i'm getting error
        })
      }
});
```

Comment: in single object multiple keys can not have same name. Create Object Array Like this `[
    {
        "city": "bangalore",
        "other": "other data",
        "pic": "bangalore.jpg"
    },
    {
        "city": "delhi",
        "pic": "delhi.jpg"
    }
]`

Comment: ok in that scenario how can i loop them

Comment: You can know which city is mapped to which pic. You need to have an array of cities to do a for each

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of objects like this.

> Object keys can not be duplicated.

```
[
    {
        "city": "bangalore",
        "other": "other data",
        "pic": "bangalore.jpg"
    },
    {
        "city": "delhi",
        "pic": "delhi.jpg"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to put each city in a separate object within an array. Object keys can't be duplicated, and even if that was somehow legal, how would you know which picture was associated with which city?  Once you have separated the cities with their pictures into separate objects, you can loop through them with by accessing the `city` property of each object in the array. Note that the first argument passed to [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is the array or object itself, *not* the property you want to display:

```js
var arr = [
    {
        "city": "bangalore",
        "other": "other data",
        "pic": "bangalore.jpg"
    },
    {
        "city": "delhi",
        "pic": "delhi.jpg"
    }
];

$.each(arr, function(i, obj) {
  console.log(obj.city);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```